# Hive files on hdfs not being deleted when managed (not external) table is dropped

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

When I drop a managed table from the Hive interactive command line, the underlying files that were created on hdfs in `/user/hive/warehouse/<databasename>.db` still exist.  This causes issues when I recreate the table with the same name and try to do

```
INSERT INTO TABLE
```

as it still contains the data that I loaded into those partitions (dt and hr partitions in my case) in my initial go around.  Only if I use

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE
```

will it then finally load the data properly, but my ETL needs to use `INSERT INTO TABLE`.

Any ideas?  I'm about ready to just create the same table but with a different name, or just go in and delete the stuff on hdfs but I'm worried if that'll break the metastore or something.  Lastly, I'm positive it is a managed table and not external.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes Hive will delete the table metadata but silently fail to move the files to the trash. Have you checked the permissions on `/user/<user>/.Trash`? Ensure that the ETL user has proper permission for this folder.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I did check trash, and no .Trash directory exists under my account or under any of the users' accounts.  I checked with `hadoop fs -ls /user/hdfs/.Trash` and got no such file or directory exists.

Comment: So it sounds like the trash feature is disabled in your Hadoop cluster. Try enabling the Hadoop trash feature temporarily in Hive and then dropping the table. You can do this via the set command (which sets Hadoop configuration values):

`SET fs.trash.interval = 30;`
`DROP TABLE <table>;`

If this shows any results then you can change it permanently in the core-site.xml configuration file.

Comment: Hello @eapeyton, I had the same issue and I tried the SET u mentioned here. Nothing changed. The part files are not being deleted from the hive warehouse. Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: I can confirm this. I also had the same issue. Hive silently failed to delete files because of permissions. Check permissions.