# Hive dropping Internal table does not delete the warehouse files of that folder

Tags: hive

[Hive files on hdfs not being deleted when managed (not external) table is dropped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114597/hive-files-on-hdfs-not-being-deleted-when-managed-not-external-table-is-droppe)

I followed the link but that didn't help.

Can anyone please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Even I had the same scenario and the solution described in the post did not work for me.

So what I did was a brute force delete from the Hive Warehouse folder. I know this might not be the best way to handle the situation, but it did help me to move ahead and create the table again without banging much of my head.

You can do the same if you want using the following command from Hadoop shell:

`hadoop fs -rm hdfs://nn.example.com/file /user/hive/warehouse/schemaname/`

Comment: But when I run the command I get
rm: Permission denied by sticky bit setting:

Comment: Then I guess you need to activate permissions for doing that..since that is the only way I can think of.

Comment: This can be a workaround, not the proper solution. interesting thing is that what is the root cause which exploits the hive concept.

Answer (score 0):

Above works, but you get permission denied because of sticky bit.

1) Either do it as superuser or

2) Run - `HADOOP_USER_NAME=<dir owner> hdfs dfs  -rmr <hdfs dir>`